# Variables in QTODBC to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

In QTODBC, with an sqlServer DB, I can do:

```
declare @client int
set @client = 5
select * from clients where client = @client
```

But it doesn't work when DB is Oracle. Which is the simplest way to do the same (without functions nor procedures nor similars, if possible...).

I've tried like:

```
declare
    client number;
begin
    client := 1234;
    select * from clients where client = &client;
end;
```

but it doesn't works too...

Any help?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12c and above, use `dbms_sql.return_result`

```
DECLARE
     l_client   NUMBER := 1234;
     x          SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     OPEN x FOR SELECT *
                  FROM clients
                WHERE client = l_client;
     dbms_sql.return_result(x);
END;
/
```

for previous versions, use `refcursor` bind variable and `print` command

```
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR
DECLARE
     l_client   NUMBER := 1234;
     x          SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     OPEN :x FOR SELECT *
                  FROM clients
                WHERE client = l_client;
END;
/

PRINT x
```

Comment: Thank you very much! First snippet worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jaume : you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: Sorry, I used to consult stackoverflow a lot but this is my second question and I didn't know that I had tot do this... Thanks for the answer and the use of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work ;-)

```
    declare
        v_client number;
    begin
        v_client := 1234;
        select * from clients where client = v_client;
    end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it doesn't work for me. QTODBC says that I need to add an 'INTO' in the select clause. Anyway, I appreciatte your post.